# Can I use torrent while I'm on the SSL VPN of my college network?

Tags: vpn, bittorrent, ssl

I'm using μTorrent 
But I connected on my college network by SSL VPN, torrent is stopped.
How can I use torrent while I'm still on my SSL VPN network?

Comment: If the traffic is blocked while connected to the school's network the you won't be able use μTorrent.  You might want to check your student handbook, people have been kicked out of schools, for using software to download torrent ( even legal torrents ).  We both know thats not the case.

Comment: What is not the case? (and an apostrophe in that's)

Comment: Have you another network, I know of people that have experienced problems when connecting to a vpn, even though there other network would allow it. (and What OS are you running?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you change the routing. A VPN will often just set the default gateway so that all traffic is routed towards the VPN. If you change the default route back to your router and only add one or more routes as necessary towards your Uni network through the VPN, you should be able to use all services as without VPN.

That being, said, if this is SSL VPN in the meaning that I know, it will not change any routing because essentially, it is not really a VPN but rather a portal giving access to very specific applications on the remote site. Since SSL VPN is running only in the browser, I don't see how it could change the routing table.